# Left join Without Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, subquery

I am getting the below output, I want the same out but without subqueries[image: Query Output].I am looking to  refine the below query by removing the subquery as it is affecting the performance of the application. Could anyone  help me to remove subquery and fetch the required data using the joins.

[image: recruitersubmission schema]

```
SELECT DISTINCT rec.requestno as requestno
    , (SELECT min(dateandtime) 
       from recruitersubmission 
       where recruitersubmission.requestno = rec.requestno) as firstsubmsion
    , (SELECT max(dateandtime) 
       from recruitersubmission 
       where recruitersubmission.requestno = rec.requestno) as lastsubmission
    , cndinterview.dateandtime as  candidatefedtime
    , cndinterview.dateandtime AS recruitertime
    , CONCAT(availabledate,' ', availabletime) AS candidateavaibledatetime
    , cndfeedback.status AS status
    , cndfeedback.offereddate AS offereddate
    , cnd.status AS onboard
    , (SELECT COUNT(recruitersubmission.requestno)
       FROM recruitersubmission 
       WHERE recruitersubmission.requestno=rec.requestno) AS totalSub
    , (select COUNT(candidatefeedback.requestno) 
       from candidatefeedback 
       WHERE candidatefeedback.requestno = rec.requestno 
          && candidatefeedback.status = 'Selected' ) as totalsel
    , (select COUNT( candidatefeedback.requestno) 
       from candidatefeedback 
       WHERE candidatefeedback.requestno = rec.requestno 
          && cndfeedback.status = 'Rejected' ) as totalrej
    , (select COUNT(candidatefeedbkonboard.requestno) 
       from candidatefeedbkonboard 
       WHERE candidatefeedbkonboard.requestno = rec.requestno 
          && cnd.status = 'Drop' ) as totaldrop
    , (select COUNT(candidatefeedbkonboard.requestno) 
       from candidatefeedbkonboard 
       WHERE candidatefeedbkonboard.requestno = rec.requestno 
          && candidatefeedbkonboard.status = 'Onboarded' ) as totalonboard
from recruitersubmission AS rec 
LEFT JOIN candidatefeedbkonboard AS cnd 
    ON rec.requestno=cnd.requestno 
LEFT JOIN candidatefeedback AS cndfeedback 
    ON rec.requestno=cndfeedback.requestno 
LEFT JOIN candidatesinterview AS cndinterview 
    ON rec.requestno=cndinterview.requestno
where rec.clientname = '$client' 
   && rec.requestno != ''  
   && rec.country = '$location' 
   && date(rec.dateandtime) between '$fromdate'
```

I want to avoid these below subqueries.

(select COUNT(candidatefeedback.requestno) from candidatefeedback WHERE candidatefeedback.requestno = rec.requestno && candidatefeedback.status = 'Selected' ) as totalsel

Comment: try please to make your query more confortable to read by using stackoverflow code edit tool.

Comment: Schema info, sample data and expected result being supplied would make this a lot easier to answer

Comment: I am getting the output but want to replace the subqueries as it is taking long time execute.

Comment: Yes you told us that already. But for us to help we need the info I mentioned

Comment: What version of MySQL are you on? Are you sure your query is actually correct? The `distinct` is always a worry, your `totalrej` and `totaldrop` subqueries probably have filters against the wrong tables. It also looks like you're concatenating strings together for your filters - this looks vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: I am running this query in phpmyadmin

Comment: 'I am running this query in phpmyadmin' - in that case tell use what the result of select version() is. NB image data is not useable whereas text is..

Comment: Server version: 10.4.20-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: mysql<>mariadb in some significant ways have added mariadb to the tags..

Comment: Is rec.requestno unique?

Comment: yes rec.requestno unique

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help friends. I figured out how to do it. Below is the solution for your refernce.

```
SELECT
    rec.requestno,
    COALESCE(totalsub, 0) AS totalsub,
    COALESCE(totalsel, 0) AS totalsel,
    COALESCE(totalrej, 0) AS totalrej
FROM recruitersubmission rec
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT requestno, COUNT(*) AS totalsub
    FROM recruitersubmission
    GROUP BY requestno
) recruitersubmission  ON recruitersubmission.requestno = rec.requestno
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  requestno,count(if(status = 'Selected',1,Null)) AS totalsel,count(if(status = 'Rejected',1,Null)) as totalrej
    FROM candidatefeedback 
    GROUP BY requestno
) candidatefeedback  ON candidatefeedback.requestno = rec.requestno


GROUP by rec.requestno Limit 0,25
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Re: your subqueries:

(SELECT min(dateandtime)
from recruitersubmission
where recruitersubmission.requestno = rec.requestno)

Needs `INDEX(requestno, dateandtime)`.  Similarly for other subqueries.

Re: Seejith's answer:

```
count(if(status = 'Selected',1,Null))
```

Can be replaced by

```
SUM(status = 'Selected')
```

thereby eliminating the need for `COALESCE(.., 0)`.

Comment: Just to point out that Sreejith both asked and answered the question.